# need to remove HTML tag from string in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I am having this(sample) HTML stored in database as a string

```
<div>
   This is test
</div>
<ul>
   <li>
      Link1
   </li>
</ul>
```

now, it could contain

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://sample.com/somelink">
```

i would like to check if this string contains `link rel` tag then replace its href with something else. and if it does not have `link rel` tag then i would like to add new one.

also, when i load up that string in my CMS, i would like to see if it exits, then i would like to extract its `href` as a string, and then i will display it somewhere on the page as a separate stirng.

please help. i have googled it but did not find any helpful solution hence no code in the question. i am also not familiar with the regex.

Note: Sorry, forgot to mention that i can not add any external lib to my project because of certain PCI implication .

Comment: This may be a good job for the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: i can not add any external lib to my project .. sorry forgot to mention that in my question at first

Comment: Your sample string does neither contain `rel` nor `href` attributes. So do we have to imagine that `Link1` actually is `<link rel="canonical" href="http://sample.com/somelink">`?

Comment: no, '<link rel="canonical" href="http://sample.com/somelink">' could be there in my sample string. so i need to find the existence...

Answer (score 4):

You should use [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex), in combination with XPATH selection of your elements and attributes

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(htmlString);

foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href and @rel]")
{
   HtmlAttribute att = link["href"];
   att.Value = FixLink(att);
}
```

Explanation of the XPATH

- `//a` means it will select all  elements in your code
   - `[@href and @rel]` means both attributes needs to be available in the selection

You can refine this pattern by doing something like this `//a[@href and @rel='canonical']`

Comment: From question: *Note: Sorry, forgot to mention that i can not add any external lib to my project because of certain PCI implication .*

Comment: If you can include the lib download the source code and include that, it will save you tons of work!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a *parser* and not regex. Use something like [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), or search on internet for something  different if you wish.

*But, do not use regex to parse html*. In order to be able to parse HTML, you need state save cappability, which regex does not provide. More on this on excessive discussion for farther reading:

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score -1):

Try it : 100% workable function for remove html tag from string.

```
public static string StripHTML(string htmlstring)
            {
                try
                {
                    string result;

                    // Remove HTML Development formatting
                    // Replace line breaks with space
                    // because browsers inserts space

                    result = htmlstring.ToString().Trim().Replace("\r", " ");
                    result = result.ToString().Trim().Replace("&nbsp;", " ");
                    result = result.ToString().Trim().Replace("nbsp;", " ");
                    result = result.ToString().Trim().Replace("nbsp", " ");
                    result = result.ToString().Trim().Replace("&amp;", " ");
                    result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result, "&nbsp;", " ");

                    // Replace line breaks with space
                    // because browsers inserts space
                    result = result.Replace("\n", " ");
                    // Remove step-formatting
                    result = result.Replace("\t", string.Empty);
                    // Remove repeating spaces because browsers ignore them
                    result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                                                                          @"( )+", " ");

                    // Remove the header (prepare first by clearing attributes)
                    result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                             @"<( )*head([^>])*>", "<head>",
                             System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                             @"(<( )*(/)( )*head( )*>)", "</head>",
                             System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                             "(<head>).*(</head>)", string.Empty,
                             System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

                    // remove all scripts (prepare first by clearing attributes)
                    result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                             @"<( )*script([^>])*>", "<script>",
                             System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                             @"(<( )*(/)( )*script( )*>)", "</script>",
                             System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    //result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                    //         @"(<script>)([^(<script>\.</script>)])*(</script>)",
                    //         string.Empty,
                    //         System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                             @"(<script>).*(</script>)", string.Empty,
                             System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

                    // remove all styles (prepare first by clearing attributes)
                    result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                             @"<( )*style([^>])*>", "<style>",
                             System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                             @"(<( )*(/)( )*style( )*>)", "</style>",
                             System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                             "(<style>).*(</style>)", string.Empty,
                             System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

                    // insert tabs in spaces of <td> tags
                    result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                             @"<( )*td([^>])*>", "\t",
                             System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

                    // insert line breaks in places of <BR> and <LI> tags
                    result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                             @"<( )*br( )*>", "\r",
                             System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                             @"<( )*li( )*>", "\r",
                             System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

                    // insert line paragraphs (double line breaks) in place
                    // if <P>, <DIV> and <TR> tags
                    result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                             @"<( )*div([^>])*>", "\r\r",
                             System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                             @"<( )*tr([^>])*>", "\r\r",
                             System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                             @"<( )*p([^>])*>", "\r\r",
                             System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

                    // Remove remaining tags like <a>, links, images,
                    // comments etc - anything that's enclosed inside < >
                    result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                             @"<[^>]*>", string.Empty,
                             System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

                    // replace special characters:
                    result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                             @" ", " ",
                             System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

                    result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                             @"&bull;", " * ",
                             System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                             @"&lsaquo;", "<",
                             System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                             @"&rsaquo;", ">",
                             System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                             @"&trade;", "(tm)",
                             System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                             @"&frasl;", "/",
                             System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                             @"&lt;", "<",
                             System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                             @"&gt;", ">",
                             System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                             @"&copy;", "(c)",
                             System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                             @"&reg;", "(r)",
                             System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    // Remove all others. More can be added, see
                    // http://hotwired.lycos.com/webmonkey/reference/special_characters/
                    result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                             @"&(.{2,6});", string.Empty,
                             System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

                    // for testing
                    //System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                    //       this.txtRegex.Text,string.Empty,
                    //       System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

                    // make line breaking consistent
                    result = result.Replace("\n", "\r");

                    // Remove extra line breaks and tabs:
                    // replace over 2 breaks with 2 and over 4 tabs with 4.
                    // Prepare first to remove any whitespaces in between
                    // the escaped characters and remove redundant tabs in between line breaks
                    result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                             "(\r)( )+(\r)", "\r\r",
                             System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                             "(\t)( )+(\t)", "\t\t",
                             System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                             "(\t)( )+(\r)", "\t\r",
                             System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                             "(\r)( )+(\t)", "\r\t",
                             System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    // Remove redundant tabs
                    result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                             "(\r)(\t)+(\r)", "\r\r",
                             System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    // Remove multiple tabs following a line break with just one tab
                    result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                             "(\r)(\t)+", "\r\t",
                             System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    // Initial replacement target string for line breaks
                    string breaks = "\r\r\r";
                    // Initial replacement target string for tabs
                    string tabs = "\t\t\t\t\t";
                    for (int index = 0; index < result.Length; index++)
                    {
                        result = result.Replace(breaks, "\r\r");
                        result = result.Replace(tabs, "\t\t\t\t");
                        breaks = breaks + "\r";
                        tabs = tabs + "\t";
                    }

                    // That's it.
                    return result;
                }
                catch
                {

                    return htmlstring;
                }
            }
```

Comment: how to ignore anchor tag